# Firefox does not run this JQuery script, but Chrome does

Tags: jquery

Firefox does not run this JQuery script, but Chrome does. What could be the reason ?

```
event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('adat');

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'index.php',
  data: 'action=profile&option=refresh&ajax=1&id=' + id,
  success: function(contentHTML) {
    alert(contentHTML);
    $('#refreshdate' + id).html('Még ' + contentHTML + ' óra');
  }
});
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in the code. Are you sure that one of the browsers isn't looking at a cached version of the page? Have you checked the console to see if there's any errors generated? It would also help to see a more complete sample of your code - what is `this` referring to? What event is this running under?

Comment: Clear cache of each browser and see the result

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  and Mohammed : I ALWAYS  load the pages with Ctrl-Shift-R, so it must be  in the newest stage; however, this script is on the page for months (but I just now realised that Firefox do nothing).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : it is a click event, and 'this' refers to the clicked <a> tag .